# How to connect Elasticsearch(8.x) using Java low level client configuration as RestHightLevelClient is deprecated

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, rest-client, low-level

I am new to ElasticSearch and trying to establish connection to elasticsearch using Java Lowlevel rest client configuration as RestHightLevelClient is deprecated.The documentation says to add below code but I am not sure where the code needs to be added.

```
RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(
    new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
    new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")).build();
```

The below RestHightLevelClient configuration works fine but it is deprecated.

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.demo.elasticsearch.repositories")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.demo.elasticsearch"})
public class ElasticSearchConfiguration
    extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration
{

    @Override
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration =
                ClientConfiguration
                    .builder()
                    .connectedTo("host:port")
                    .usingSsl()
                    .withBasicAuth("username","password")
                    .build();

        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me with java low level rest client config

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

Try replacing your second code-block with this one:

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.demo.elasticsearch.repositories")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.demo.elasticsearch"})
public class ElasticSearchConfiguration
    extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration
{

        RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")).build();

        // Create the transport with a Jackson mapper
        ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(
                restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

        // And create the API client
        ElasticsearchClient esClient = new 
        ElasticsearchClient(transport);

        return esClient;
}
```

This worked for me to get the connection working with a local elasticsearch.

---

Old post:

I am struggeling with this too. I also try to connect with BasicAuth to https URL.

I found the following documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/_basic_authentication.html
Maybe it is helpful for you. Let me know in case you managed to solve this problem.

I currently replaced your block with

```
    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchClient elasticsearchClient() {
        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider =
                new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, password));

        RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(
                        new HttpHost("mycustomurlHidden.com", 9243))
                .setHttpClientConfigCallback(new RestClientBuilder.HttpClientConfigCallback() {

                    public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(
                            HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
                        return httpClientBuilder
                                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
                    }
                });
```

I am still getting an error, but maybe it works for you